# Windows Store App: generics in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, generics, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to instantiate generic types in XAML for Windows Store App?

For example, I have page base class:

```cs
public class PageBase<T> : Page
{
}
```

How to create page of type `PageBase<string>` in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible out of the box.

You can try a workaround (for example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx)), but from personal experience, I wouldn't recommend it, things get messy really fast. We've tried to implement the above solution, but it turned out that it is easier to revise the design than handling generics from XAML.

In your case, I would recommend created derived classes from your base page using a specific type.

Comment: The part that I'm confused about is that in the post you reference, he states that "For the most part, Xaml does not support generics.  The one exception to that is that generics are supported on the root tag of your Xaml, if you’re compiling the Xaml."  Since the page element would be the root tag of your xaml, should it not work then?